# Create form dynamically based on array data in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I constructed an array from the rest API data as shown below

```
arr = [ {'model1': 'value1', 'type': 'text'},
        {'model2': 'true', 'type': 'radio'},
        {'model3': 'value3', 'type': 'text'},
      ];
```

Here how can i to generate dynamic form for e.g., first element `ng-model` name as `model1` and its `value` as `value1` and its type as `text/radio`

Comment: You have to first make an attempt. However, I would advise against that anyway. Use Angular's built in form support.

Comment: are you telling me to use `ng-form`?

Comment: That is a better option. What version of Angular is this?

Comment: Am using angular 1st version.. 1.5

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms. Dynamically creating a form is not a good option.

Comment: then what is the good option?

Comment: Of course creating dynamic forms is 100% ok. Array you constructed is bad reconstruct it to ~ {controlName: 'model1', value: 'value1', 'type': 'text'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First fix the names of your array item properties so they don't include the index in their name as that defeats the purpose. Change the array to

```
arr = [
  {'model': 'value1', 'type': 'text'},
  {'model': 'true', 'type': 'radio'},
  {'model': 'value3', 'type': 'text'},
];
```

You need to iterate over your array to generate the form like so

```
<form form="arrForm" ng-submit="arrForm.submit()">
  <section ng-repeat="value in arr>
    <label for="value-{{$index}}-model">Model {{$index}}</label>
    <input ng-model="value.model" name="value-{{$index}}-model">

    <section>
      <label for="value-{{$index}}-type">Type {{$index}} </label>
      <input ng-repeat="type in possibleTypes" type="radio" ng-model="value.type" ng-value="type" name="value-{{$index}}-type">
    </section>
  </section>

  <input type="submit" value="Save All" ng-disabled="arrForm.$invalid">
</form>
```

However, consider using an AngularJS form library. [FormlyJS](http://angular-formly.com) is the best by miles.

Comment: without controlName in arr I am not sure you can get something which you can work with... Also guess you meant something else in ng-model="value.type"

Comment: @Petr_Averyanov This is AngularJS. See the tags

Comment: @Aluan Haddad thank you .. i got the idea.. reconstructed the array

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I see what you meant about model. I added value binding